# Несколько XPath для одного XmlDataProvider WPF

Tags: xpath, c#, wpf, xml

Имеются 2 DataGrid и один XmlDataProdiver для работы с XML-файлом. Структура XML-файла:

```
<Setting>
  <Element Name="..." Offset="..." ID="...">
    <Item Name="..." Type="..." Count="..." ID="..." />
    <Item Name="..." Type="..." Count="..." ID="..." />
    <Item Name="..." Type="..." Count="..." ID="..." />
    ...
  </Element>
  <Element Name="..." Offset="..." ID="...">
    <Item Name="..." Type="..." Count="..." ID="..." />
    <Item Name="..." Type="..." Count="..." ID="..." />
  </Element>
  ...
</Setting>
```

Необходимо в один DataGrid вывести значения атрибутов всех Element'ов, в другой - значения атрибутов всех Item'ов заданного Element'a, используя тот же XmlDataProvider.

XAML для вывода значений атрибутов всех Element'ов в первый DataGrid:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding}">
  <DataGrid.DataContext>
    <XmlDataProvider x:Name="xml_setting" XPath="/Setting/Element"/>
  </DataGrid.DataContext>
  <DataGrid.Columns>
    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Название" Width="*" Binding="{Binding XPath=@Name}"/>
    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Смещение" Width="80" Binding="{Binding XPath=@Offset}"/>
    <DataGridTextColumn Header="ID" Width="80" Binding="{Binding XPath=@ID}"/>
  </DataGrid.Columns>
```

Пробовал устанавливать XPath у XmlDataProvider'a в значение "/Setting", а XPath у столбцов в значения /Element/[[@Name](/users/9080/namespace12345)](/users/9080/namespace12345), /Element/@Offset и /Element/[[@ID](/users/11054/idd)](/users/11054/idd), но выводятся значения атрибутов только первого Element'a.

Как можно работать с одним XmlDataProvider'ом, прибиндивая к разным столбцам разных DataGrid'ов получение значений атрибутов разных узлов?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У меня сработало вот так:

```
<Window x:Class="XPathTest.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.Resources>
        <XmlDataProvider x:Key="xml_setting">
            <x:XData>
                <Setting Name="Setting 1" xmlns="">
                    <Element Name="Element 1" Offset="Offset 1" ID="Id 1">
                        <Item Name="Item 11" Type="Type 11" Count="11" ID="Id 11" />
                        <Item Name="Item 12" Type="Type 12" Count="12" ID="Id 12" />
                        <Item Name="Item 13" Type="Type 13" Count="13" ID="Id 13" />
                    </Element>
                    <Element Name="Element 2" Offset="Offset 2" ID="Id 2">
                        <Item Name="Item 21" Type="Type 21" Count="21" ID="Id 21" />
                        <Item Name="Item 22" Type="Type 22" Count="22" ID="Id 22" />
                    </Element>
                </Setting>
            </x:XData>
        </XmlDataProvider>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <DataGrid
            AutoGenerateColumns="False"
            ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource xml_setting},
                                  XPath=/Setting/Element}" >
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn
                    Header="Название" Width="*" Binding="{Binding XPath=@Name}"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn
                    Header="Смещение" Width="80" Binding="{Binding XPath=@Offset}"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn
                    Header="ID" Width="80" Binding="{Binding XPath=@ID}"/>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
        <DataGrid
            AutoGenerateColumns="False" Grid.Row="1"
            ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource xml_setting},
                                  XPath=/Setting/Element/Item}">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn
                    Header="Название" Width="*" Binding="{Binding XPath=@Name}"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn
                    Header="Тип" Width="80" Binding="{Binding XPath=@Type}"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn
                    Header="Количество" Width="80" Binding="{Binding XPath=@Count}"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn
                    Header="ID" Width="80" Binding="{Binding XPath=@ID}"/>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```